# Only display current y-value on ToolTip in chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, tooltip

I am working on a developing a chart using Chart.js and I want to only display te y-axis value in the tool-tip. Currently it displays:

date
name_of_line: measurement

ex.
Jan 1, 2020, 8:00:00 AM
5th Percentile: 100 oz.

And this is what I want it to look like:
5th Percentile: 100 oz

Here is the code I have so far to format the y-axis tooltip:

```
callbacks: {
                    label: function(context) {
                        let label = context.dataset.label || '';

                        if (label) {
                            label += ': ';
                        }

                        if (context.parsed.y !== null) {
                            label += new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(context.parsed.y);
                            label += ' oz';
                        }

                        return label;
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its work for me

for only x values

```
      tooltips:{
         callbacks: {
    title: function(tooltipItems, data) {
      return '';
    },
    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
      var datasetLabel = '';
      var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
      return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
    }
  }


  }
```

for only y values

```
tooltips: {
enabled: true,
displayColors:false,
callbacks: {
    label:(tooltipItem)=>{
        return tooltipItem.parsed;
    },
}
```

},